# how to escape < sign in php regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Should I add some character/s before or after `<` character (which is in string I'm trying to extract something from - it's an html page) when doing preg match?

Comment: I guess they don't like the lack of knowledge the question displays, but personally I thought that was the whole point of the site.  Before you didn't know that < didn't need to be escaped in regular expressions... now you do.  I'll give you an up for asking the question and braving the criticism.

Comment: well, i add 'sorry if it's dumb question' like every 2nd question i post but i guess that's not enough for some... thanks to everyone who upvoted my question back to 0, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need to escape < unless you are saving a user generated data and then you should be concerned about security and XSS.

Comment: thanks for the down vote :) I guess that's what I should expect for answering such questions!

Comment: There appear to be some people here who are down vote trigger happy.  Luckily a few up votes erases the damage from a down ;)

Answer (score 6):

you don't need to escape it, it's not a special character in regexes.

Answer (score 2):

Some regex parsers treat the "<" and ">" symbols as the word boundaries (GNU Basic & Extended regular expressions). See [this great site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) for all regex-related info.